# How can I access the GIT command arguments from a hook script

Tags: git, hook, githooks

Can I access the git command-line from a git hook?

E.g.
git commit -a -m "some commit message"

now, in the `pre-commit` hook, I want to see if the used `-m` or used the editor.
alternatively, to see that the user used `-a` to add the files.

Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is "no". The longer answer is that you can *sometimes* use OS facilities to scrounge around and search for command line options, but it's generally unwise because it's generally difficult or impossible to do this reliably. Use some other method to find out what you need to know (whatever that may be).

Comment: @torek 1 word: Bummer. 
I tried using bash DEBUG to record the command, but as you said it is merely a hack, and I don't like it at all.

Comment: just curious why you would want this information ?

Comment: @AnthonySottile I want to create switches for some hooks, e.g. `pre-push` I check submodules has no modifications, and are pushed to server. i want to be able to override this behaviour like `git push --allow-modified-submodule` ...

Comment: @TomerW you can't specify arguments that git doesn't understand to its commands so your idea is DOA -- a classic case of an XY problem :)  you can however set environment variables

Answer (score 0):

On a POSIX system you could use `ps` to see the arguments.

There are significant failure modes;

- What if there is more than one `git` process?
- Doesn't work on ms-windows, though that might have similar functionality.